# No access to public static final String

Tags: java, object

Hello people im new to Java. I'm having problems to access the created ID and password in my public static void main. I'd be glad if you could help me. It is my first time that I want to use different objects in my project.

```
public class Nonfettcalc  {   

        public static final String createID(int length){
            String allowedChars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            StringBuilder ID = new StringBuilder(length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                ID.append(allowedChars.charAt(random.nextInt(allowedChars.length())));
            }
            return ID.toString();
        }

        public static String createPassword(int length){
            String allowedChars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP!§$%&?*+#";
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            StringBuilder pass = new StringBuilder(length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                pass.append(allowedChars.charAt(random.nextInt(allowedChars.length())));
            }

            System.out.println(pass);
            return pass.toString();
        }

        public static void main (String[] args){        
            pass = ID;
            ID = pass;

            createPassword = createID;
            createID = createPassword;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do ? What is your error ?

Comment: You need to learn more about variables and methods. You aren't declaring `pass` or `ID`. And you aren't calling your methods (plus with any parameters)

Comment: I got no access to these Strings in my void main; pass = ID; createPassword = createID; ID = pass; createID = createPassword;

Comment: @cricket_007 pass and ID is declarated as StringBuilder?

Comment: Not within the scope of the main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in main method is completely inapropriate. First of all you should define variables and their types.

For example:

```
public static void main (String[] args){        
    String id = createID(5);
    String password = createPassword(8);
}
```

And then you could use your id and email via that variables.

Comment: Thank you very much buddy I got it now! Thaaaaaaanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any reason here to declare your methods as final. That also isn't the problem.

You need to *declare* your variables and *call* your methods.

```
    public static void main (String[] args){        
        String ID = createID(7);
        String pass = createPassword(10);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much buddy I got it now! Thaaaaaaanks